# matlab: sum values of different sized subarrays without loop

Tags: matlab, max, vectorization, min, arrays

I wonder if it is possible to get min/max values of different sized subarrays 
without using a loop in matlab.

```
% create a 1D vector with arbitory floating point values
A = rand(100,1,'double');

% get start indexes of sections of A (eg. A>0.9)
pos01 = A>0.9;
posIdx= [1;find(pos01);size(A,1)];

% if 1 or size(A,1) where not required, remove them
posIdx = unique(posIdx); 

% min/max all sections:
for ix=1:size(posIdx,1)-1
    Amin(ix) = min(A(posIdx(ix):posIdx(ix+1)));
    Amax(ix) = max(A(posIdx(ix):posIdx(ix+1)));
end
```

This last row can be very slow if you have a very large vector A and lots of sections.
I wonder how to vectorize this loop in matlab.

I tried to come up with a solution using arrayfun, remap, bsxfun and others.
But all the solutions I can think of, require the sections to have equal size - which is not the case :(

Any ideas ?

best,
Jens Henrik

Comment: Do you really need the sections to overlap in the last/fist element?

Comment: I can avoid the overlap. The accumarray is doing the job. Great.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cumsum` and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
A = rand(100,1,'double');
pos01 = A > 0.9;
subs = ( pos01(1) == 0 ) + cumsum( pos01(:) ); % convert posIdx to subs. note the special treatment of the first entry. 
Amin = accumarray( subs, A, [], @min );
Amax = accumarray( subs, A, [], @max );
```

Comment: +1 nicely done with accumarray, probably much faster than a bsxfun implementation..

Comment: Have you noticed that the OP overlaps the sections by one element? Other than that, your approach would be the way to go (I was writing an answer based on that when I say yours)

Comment: @LuisMendo interesting point. I did not notice this detail. It does make things a bit more complicated... I'll see if I can fix.

Comment: I think `Amax = max(Amax, A([find(pos01); end]));` would work. +1

Comment: accumarray() is just the command I was searching for - great. Thanks  Shai, thanks Luis - your comments are really helpfull! I will test, if this brings the hoped speedup over a simple for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

`bsxfun` approach to replace your for-loop part -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@le,1:size(A,1),posIdx(2:end)) & bsxfun(@ge,1:size(A,1),posIdx(1:end-1));
t1 = t1';
t2 = A(:,ones(1,size(t1,2))).*t1;
t2(~t1)=nan;
Amin = nanmin(t2);
Amax = nanmax(t2);
```

Comment: [tag:bsxfun] is a lot of fun, but I'm afraid it is not the right place to use it: (a) the resulting code is very difficult to understand. (b) it uses too much memory o(n^2).

Comment: @Shai Thanks for the feedback. Agree with you on that, it does look slower for this problem. But, `bsxfun` will always use `o(n^2)` and if provided enough computing resources and memory-bandwidth it could be useful. This `o(n^2)` memory requirement is applicable for all solutions using `bsxfun`. On the explaining part, sometimes I let the asker take the initiative and ask about specific portions of the code if there's any query.

Comment: Indeed `bsxfun` will always use o(n^2) but in many cases it is justified: I'm afraid this is not the case **here**. I feel like for this **specific** task `bsxfun` is not the right tool, for many many other tasks `bsxfun` is very useful and I think every Matlab programer should make himself/herself familiar with.

Comment: +1 for correctly handling the one-element overlap the OP seems to want

Comment: @LuisMendo Actually I am not handling that at all, this code only replaces the for-loop part. Appreciate the +1! :) Still wondering if there's a vectorized solution that would beat the for-loops part though.

Comment: Great ideas and comments. Thanks!